# how to properly use a C# indexer property

Tags: c#, wpf, indexing

I am taking over a WPF C# team project.

One of the class inherits from an abstract class having this property:

```
[Dynamic]
        public dynamic this[string key] { get; set; }
```

I m not familiar with this but I take it it sets an indexer property the class objects?

I need to mock such an object by adding a variable to this indexer.
How am I supposed to do?
I was expecting something like this:

```
this.Add(myKey, myValue);
```

but the compiler strongly objects :)

How am I supposed to add items into this indexer??

thx

Comment: To which list do you exactly want to add the value ? Do you have a private list inside that class ?

Comment: hm, I don't know, I just realize that the concerned class is into an external DLL (that I don't have access to).

However, for mock purpose, I suppose that I can derive this class and override the indexer accessors?

Comment: So you can't have a default `{ get; set; }` this doesn't work. You must implement these methods and add the passed value to some collection or you'll lose it.

Comment: OK I got it thx for helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An indexer on a class makes instances look as though they are some kind of array keyed by whatever parameters you wish rather than only integers

```
var existingValue = this["someKey"];
this["someKey"] = newValue;
```

To implement the class you'd do something like this

```
public class Mine : ThatAbstractClass
{
  Dictionary<string, dynamic> IndexerValues = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

  public override dynamic this[string key]
  {
    get { return IndexerValues[key]; }
    set { IndexerValues[key] = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about. Thanks for extending your answer :)

Comment: That's okay. I actually extended it before I saw your comment (just now) :)